# Is there a way to inspect iOS Outlook App email code?

Tags: css, ios, outlook, media-queries, inspect

I'm having a problem while sending a email. All the email clients is showing correctly, but iOS Outlook app is probably ignoring the media query.
I've already tried to adjust the media query  like this:

```
body[data-outlook-cycle] .container { width: 480px !important; }
```

It kinda helped, but it did not resolve the problem.

**Is there a way to inspect iPhone's Outlooks App email via mac ?**

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://github.com/M-J-Robbins/emailTargeting
"renders in webmail if you drop the body and just use the attribute."